# Division of Square Root of Primes are Irrational

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers

Prove that for any distinct primes $p$ and $q$, the ratio $\frac{\sqrt p}{\sqrt q}$ is irrational.

I know that separately $\sqrt p$ and $\sqrt q$ are irrational, so my initial thought process was to show that they are each irrational, but it is not always true that an irrational number divided by an irrational number is also irrational, could someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Suppose that $\sqrt {\frac pq}=\frac mn$ with $(m,n)=1$.  Then a little work shows that $n^2p=m^2q$.  Unique factorization shows that $q|n$ whence $q^2$ divides the left hand.  Deduce that $q|m$, a contradiction.

Comment: Does (m,n)=1 mean they are relatively prime? I understand where $n^2p = m^2q$ comes from. We know $q$ does not divide $p$ because they are distinct primes, then $q$ divides $n^2$ which means $q$ divides $n$. How do we show that $q$ divides $m$?

Comment: Yes, $(m,n)=1$ means the gcd is $1$, hence relatively prime. Since $q|n$ we can write $n=qk$.  Thus we can rewrite to get $q^2k^2p=m^2q$  divide by $q$ to get $qk^2p=m^2$ whence $q|m^2$ whence $q|m$.

Comment: Thank you. So then the contradiction comes from the fact that m and n are relatively prime, so that they couldn't have a common factor of $q$, right? I'm sorry but i am still a bit confused on why this contraction makes it irrational?

Comment: Yes, as to the nature of the contradiction.  If you had a rational square root, you could put it in least terms.  The contradiction here shows that this is not possible in this case.  This is the same contradiction that appears in the [standard proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Square_Root_of_2_is_Irrational) that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

**We show it using a proof by contradiction.**

Suppose that you can write $\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$ = $\frac{a}{b}$ Where p and q are primes and a,b are rational numbers and that $\frac{a}{b}$ cannot be reduced.

Then $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$

(1) $\frac{p}{q} *{b^2}= {a^2}$

Then a is a multiple of $\frac{p}{q}$.

(2) $a = k * \frac{p}{q}$

Insert (2) in (1):
$\frac{p}{q} *{b^2}= {(k * \frac{p}{q})^2}$

$\frac{p}{q} *{b^2}= {k^2 * \frac{p^2}{q^2}}$

Divide by $\frac{p}{q}$:

${b^2}= {k^2 * \frac{p}{q}}$

We see that both b and a have common factors, but due to our initial statement that a and b have no common factors, $\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$ is not rrational.

Comment: In case this is helpful to anybody else, this step is due to the unique prime factorisation theorem (see https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-prove-that-square-root-15-is-irrational):

(2) $a = k * \frac{p}{q}$